# Layout issue, big vertical space between the viewtext elemens and divider in list item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

below is a list_item layout. I don't understand why there is a big vertical space between the viewtext elemens and divider element inside a list item row ? What is wrong with this layout?

[Screenshot here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzoPYP14icOeb0VyeFMwVXJzLWM/edit?usp=sharing)

My layout xml for list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/companyName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_selector"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exchange"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_light_selector"
            android:layout_below="@id/companyName"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/symbol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_light_selector"
            android:layout_below="@id/companyName"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/exchange"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_selector"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/change"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/table_stock_change_text"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/price"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percentChange"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/table_stock_change_text"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/change"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/change"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/change"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the fragment:

```
public class StockListFragment extends ItemListFragment<CurrentStock> {

    @Inject BootstrapServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    @Inject LogoutService logoutService;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Injector.inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setEmptyText(R.string.no_stocks);


    }

    @Override
    protected void configureList(Activity activity, ListView listView) {
        super.configureList(activity, listView);

        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        listView.setDividerHeight(0);

        getListAdapter().addHeader(activity.getLayoutInflater()
                        .inflate(R.layout.stock_list_item_labels, null));
    }

    @Override
    LogoutService getLogoutService() {
        return logoutService;
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<List<CurrentStock>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        final List<CurrentStock> initialItems = items;
        return new ThrowableLoader<List<CurrentStock>>(getActivity(), items) {
            @Override
            public List<CurrentStock> loadData() throws Exception {

                try {
                    List<CurrentStock> latest = null;

                    if(getActivity() != null)
                        latest = serviceProvider.getService(getActivity()).getStocks();

                    if (latest != null)
                        return latest;
                    else
                        return Collections.emptyList();
                } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();
                    if (activity != null)
                        activity.finish();
                    return initialItems;
                }
            }
        };

    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        CurrentStock currentStock = ((CurrentStock) l.getItemAtPosition(position));

        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), StockActivity.class).putExtra(STOCK, currentStock));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<CurrentStock>> loader, List<CurrentStock> items) {
        super.onLoadFinished(loader, items);

    }

    @Override
    protected int getErrorMessage(Exception exception) {
        return R.string.error_loading_stocks;
    }

    @Override
    protected SingleTypeAdapter<CurrentStock> createAdapter(List<CurrentStock> items) {
        return new StockListAdapter(getActivity().getLayoutInflater(), items);
    }
}
```

This is the adapter

```
public class StockListAdapter extends SingleTypeAdapter<CurrentStock> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd");

    /**
     * Create adapter
     *
     * @param inflater
     * @param items
     */
    public StockListAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, List<CurrentStock> items) {
        super(inflater, R.layout.stock_list_item);
        setItems(items);
    }

    /**
     * Create adapter
     *
     * @param inflater
     */
    public StockListAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this(inflater, null);

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        final String id = getItem(position).getSymbol();
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(id) ? id.hashCode() : super
                .getItemId(position);
    }
/**/
    @Override
    protected int[] getChildViewIds() {
        return new int[] { R.id.companyName, R.id.exchange, R.id.symbol, R.id.price, R.id.change, R.id.percentChange };
    }

    @Override
    protected void update(int position, CurrentStock currentStock) {
        setText(0, currentStock.getCompanyName());
        setText(1, currentStock.getExchange());
        setText(2, currentStock.getSymbol());
        setText(3, currentStock.getPrice().toString());
        setText(4, currentStock.getChange().toString());
        setText(5, currentStock.getPercentChange());
    }


}
```

I don't have the listview it selvf. Btw. I need a divider except top and bottom divider ?

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: this code doesn't contains any divider

Comment: @DineshPrajapati: it's about divider list ... let's see the screen-shot first

Comment: The divider is coded in the adapter.

Comment: The screenshot is added.

Comment: can you show what you mean? ... how did you coded it? Wasn't `divider` enough for ListView?

Comment: just a suggestion, just try giving margintop and paddingtop ="0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your code where you're using your divider code. By the way, why are you doing this? ... since ListView has its `divider` and `dividerHeight`?

Here's what I've came up with in a couple of minutes of coding using above layout (only removed the `textColor` attributes):
[image]

The code for above list:

```
public class MyListActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.so_list_layout);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.localListView);
        fillListView();
    }

    private void fillListView() {
        final List<LDataRow> data = getRowData();
        ArrayAdapter<LDataRow> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyListActivity.LDataRow>(this,
                R.layout.so_list_row, data) {
            private LDataRow getDataRow(int position) {
                return data.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                LDataRow row = getDataRow(position);
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(MyListActivity.this).inflate(
                            R.layout.so_list_row, parent, false);
                }
                TextView companyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyName);
                companyName.setText(row.getCompanyName());
                TextView exchange = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exchange);
                exchange.setText(row.getExchange());
                TextView symbol = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.symbol);
                symbol.setText(row.getSymbol());
                TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
                price.setText(String.valueOf(row.getPrice()));
                TextView change = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.change);
                change.setText(String.valueOf(row.getChange()));
                TextView percentChange = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.percentChange);
                percentChange.setText(String.valueOf(row.getPercentChange()));
                return convertView;
            }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private List<LDataRow> getRowData() {
        ArrayList<LDataRow> result = new ArrayList<MyListActivity.LDataRow>();
        result.add(new LDataRow("Facebook", "Nasdaq", "E", 52.445, 0.0, 0));
        result.add(new LDataRow("Advanced Micro", "NYSE", "D", 3.23, 0.0, 0));
        result.add(new LDataRow("Genmas", "CPH", "G", -100, -3.0, -20.0));
        return result;
    }

    private static class LDataRow {
        private String companyName;

        private String exchange;

        private String symbol;

        private double price;

        private double change;

        private double percentChange;

        public LDataRow(String companyName, String exchange, String symbol, double price,
                double change, double percentChange) {
            this.companyName = companyName;
            this.exchange = exchange;
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.price = price;
            this.change = change;
            this.percentChange = percentChange;
        }

        public String getCompanyName() {
            return companyName;
        }

        public String getExchange() {
            return exchange;
        }

        public String getSymbol() {
            return symbol;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public double getChange() {
            return change;
        }

        public double getPercentChange() {
            return percentChange;
        }

    }
}
```

Use this in top `RelativeLayout` to have a bottom spacing:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp" >
```

**EDIT** If you want to customize the divider, you can very well specify a custom drawable and a size. Here's what I've done with a simple `layer-list`, `my_so_divider.xml`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Set it in the ListView:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/localListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ffff"
    android:divider="@drawable/my_so_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="24dp"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false" >

</ListView>
```

Check the `footerDividersEnabled`, `headerDividersEnabled`, `divider` and `dividerHeight` attributes ... Feel free to play around with the drawable. The effect in below image:
[image]

Comment: I added the listfragment and listadapter. Please see what I have made wrong ? Btw. I need the divider shown except top and bottom divider hidden.

Comment: Updated answer for improving divider ... Have a look at that

Comment: Nice, I really need to keep the RelativeLayout I have made instead of LinearLayout. Can you see why there are big space as dipected in the screenshot. What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: I'm not using any linearlayot

Comment: ... as said: I am not using any `LinearLayout` - just using your layout that you provided. I just made small adjustments to `ListView` and provided the custom divider drawable. Does that help?

Comment: It helped. In my description I have provided the layout, listfragment and listadapter. I just don't understand why I get a vertical space between the text and divider as shown in the screenshot. The other guys provided the linearlayout but I'm intressted in finding out why my RelativeLayout doesn't work. I better like your solution since you help me witht he Relativelayout. It will be very help for me to understand why my relativelayout is broken.

Comment: You said that you're setting the list divider in code, is that right? Because using your relative layout just in the way you have provided it shows the list as in my first top image.

Comment: Yes, the divider is set in the code. But how do I remove the header and footer space for header like you you shown in your top image ?

Comment: both `footerDividersEnabled` and `headerDividersEnabled` set to false as I did in XML layout where you have the ListView

Comment: at least give some credits to this answer by upvoting, since you accepted another answer that according to your statements didn't respect your requirements

Comment: Sorry,  I accepted tre wrong post. I accepted yours,  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/companyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_light_selector"
            android:text="companyName"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/symbol"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/table_text_light_selector"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="symbol"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exchange"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="exchange"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/table_text_light_selector"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_light_selector"
            android:text="price"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/percentChange"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="percentChange"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/table_text_light_selector"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/change"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="change"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/table_text_light_selector"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.. It will give you the similar result you are in need of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/companyName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="facebook"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_selector"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="facebook"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_selector"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exchange"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="facebook"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_light_selector"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percentChange"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="22%"
            android:textColor="@color/table_stock_change_text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/change"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0.0"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/table_stock_change_text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```